# Declaring an array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to declare an array of strings but Java is complaining when I do this:
String[] ss = ("A", "B", "C", "D");

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mre - the question is basic but it is clear, concise, well titled and potentially useful for other beginners. The answers should work as a simple howto. I think there is nothing wrong with an upvote for that.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try replacing the parentheses with braces:

```
String[] ss = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
```